# Why X0 equals zero?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

The question is as shown below:
[image]

The answer is as shown below:
[image]

**Everything is clear except based on what did he assume that X0 = 0?**

Below are the reference for formulas
[image]

Below is my trial:
[image]

Comment: If the input is AC coupled, you can take the DC component to be 0. Therefore you can specify X0 to be 0 to keep the math clean, and require AC coupling at the input.

Answer (score 1):

He is not assuming X<sub>0</sub> to be 0, he is *defining* X<sub>0</sub> to be 0.

The formula for the amplitude of the coefficients is undefined at coefficient 0. If you try to calculate it from the formula given, you will arrive at zero, infinity, or arguably any number in between.

It's rather like the behaviour of the Fourier transform of a pulse response. You can fit the ratio sin(kx)/kx to the entire function, except at x=0, where you again have a 0/0. The important thing here is that the thing you are modelling is defined at x=0, and the arithmetical formula apparently doesn't fit, so is usually defined for x=0 when you first meet this formulation.

There are techniques to determine the value of f(x)/g(x) where both f and g tend to zero at the same value of x on to a more thorough footing, by expanding f and g in polynomials in x, and cancelling terms. However, that detail is beyond the scope of the question you've been set. You might however try doing it for sin(x)/x as a fun exercise for yourself.

Comment: he is defining X0 to be 0! why 0? Can I define it to be 5 or no?

Comment: @OMAR I don't know, it's his question, he can set it up how he likes. Question - would the answer be different if X0 were some other value?

Comment: No, it will not be different. Because X0 is NOT part of the third harmonic. Right?

Comment: please make your reply "Question - would the answer be different if X0 were some other value?" formal.